# fullpage.js issue positioning navigation button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am currently using the fullpage.js plugin for my website, I created a slide in navigation bar and I am now placing the pancake to open it on the first section of fullpage. I am trying to position it in the top left corner of the page, but I can't figure out how. Here is the code. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<div class="section"><span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span><h2 class="animated fadeInDown">GTX 1080</h2></div>
```

edit: here is all of my code: https://anotepad.com/notes/pjccfy

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNrJ5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give me very little code to go by, but I'm assuming you want a similar navigation as on the fullPage.js demo page.

Using CSS:

```
.section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

As I said, I have very little to go by so I don't even know if `.section` is the correct class to apply this positioning to. Would be great if you could provide a complete page. If you want the element to have some spacing between the browser borders, you can increase the values for `top` and `left` to say, `20px`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure how much code to include, my page isn't hosted but I can include a download to it, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thanks. I've grabbed the code and the "hamburger" or "pancake" is in the top-left of the page, which is what you wanted, right? It currently does not follow when you scroll, is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Strange, when I view it in Chrome it is just above the text in the center of the screen I'll add an image.

Comment: @Kuebiko I've made a CodePen of your project, and made a few changes. Take a look: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwbPEE Is that what you wanted? I added a class `hamburger` to the span element with the rules in my answer. And some z-index.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand z-index and its use. Appreciate the help.